# Solving dangling if, elsif, and else in Bison without associativity declarations

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, bison, ambiguity, dangling-else

I am implementing a parser for a language that has if-elsif-else statements and can't seem to make my grammar unambiguous. Our compilers class was given a handout on solving the dangling else problem for if-else statements using a match/unmatched approaches as follows:

```
%token IF EXP ELSE XX

stmts: stmts stmt ';'
     | stmt ';' 
     ; 

stmt : matched
     | unmatched
     ;

matched: IF '(' EXP ')' matched ELSE matched
      | XX
      ;

unmatched : IF '(' EXP ')' matched 
      | IF '(' EXP ')' unmatched
      | IF '(' EXP ')' matched ELSE unmatched
      ;
```

The grammar documentation provided for our language is defined to have productions involving if - elsif- else where:

```
selectionStmt → IF simpleExpression THEN statement elsifList 
      | IF simpleExpression THEN statement elsifList ELSE statement

elsifList → elsifList ELSIF simpleExpression THEN statement
      | *empty*
```

where the lowercase words are productions and the uppercase are terminals.

These provided productions are ambiguous and have to be solved in the grammar implementation in bison. Here is the progress I've made on actually implementing it into Bison:

```
statement: stmtMatched
     | selectionStmtUnmatched

elsifList: elsifList ELSIF simpleExpression THEN statement
     | %empty

stmtMatched: IF simpleExpression THEN stmtMatched elsifList ELSE 
stmtMatched
       | otherStatement

selectionStmtUnmatched: IF simpleExpression THEN statement elsifList
       | IF simpleExpression THEN stmtMatched elsifList ELSE 
selectionStmtUnmatched

otherStatement: expressionStmt
          | compoundStmt
          | iterationStmt
          | returnStmt
          | breakStmt
```

Any suggestions on changing the grammar to accommodate the elsif productions similarly to using matched and unmatched statements to solving the dangling if-else problem and get rid of any shift/reduce and reduce/reduce errors?

Edit 1:
I've made more progress on a simpler version of the grammar to ensure that elsifLists can only follow matched statements:

```
stmt: matched
| unmatched

matched: IF '(' EXP ')' THEN matched elsifList ELSE matched
   | %empty

unmatched: IF '(' EXP ')' THEN matched elsifList
     | IF '(' EXP ')' THEN unmatched
     | IF '(' EXP ')' THEN matched elsifList ELSE unmatched

elsifList: elsifList ELSIF EXP THEN stmt
     | %empty
```

But I am still getting shift/reduce conflicts:

```
State 12

    3 matched: IF '(' EXP ')' THEN matched elsifList . ELSE matched
    5 unmatched: IF '(' EXP ')' THEN matched elsifList .
    7          | IF '(' EXP ')' THEN matched elsifList . ELSE unmatched
    8 elsifList: elsifList . ELSIF EXP THEN stmt

    ELSE   shift, and go to state 13
    ELSIF  shift, and go to state 14

    ELSE      [reduce using rule 5 (unmatched)]
    ELSIF     [reduce using rule 5 (unmatched)]
    $default  reduce using rule 5 (unmatched)
```

Edit 2:
I've made enough progress with the simple grammar to ensure that elsif statements are preceeded by matched statements. The resulting grammar is:

```
stmt: matched
    | unmatched

matched: IF '(' EXP ')' THEN matched elsifList ELSE matched
       | %empty

unmatched: IF '(' EXP ')' THEN matched elsifList
         | IF '(' EXP ')' THEN unmatched
         | IF '(' EXP ')' THEN matched elsifList ELSE unmatched

elsifList: elsifList ELSIF EXP THEN matched
         | %empty
```

I've updated the actual grammar for the parser for the actual language to ensure that unmatched statements can not be followed by an elsifList and that elsifLists can only be followed by matched statements:

```
statement :     stmtMatched |
                selectionStmtUnmatched
                ;


otherStatement : expressionStmt 
                | compoundStmt 
                | iterationStmt 
                | returnStmt
                | breakStmt
                ;

elsifList :     elsifList ELSIF simpleExpression THEN stmtMatched 
                | %empty
                ;

stmtMatched : IF simpleExpression THEN stmtMatched elsifList ELSE stmtMatched
            | otherStatement
            ;

selectionStmtUnmatched : IF simpleExpression THEN stmtMatched elsifList
                | IF simpleExpression THEN selectionStmtUnmatched 
                | IF simpleExpression THEN stmtMatched elsifList ELSE selectionStmtUnmatched
```

The resulting grammar is still giving me 2 shift/reduce conflicts though:

```
State 164

   44 elsifList: elsifList . ELSIF simpleExpression THEN stmtMatched
   46 stmtMatched: IF simpleExpression THEN stmtMatched elsifList . ELSE stmtMatched
   48 selectionStmtUnmatched: IF simpleExpression THEN stmtMatched elsifList .
   50                       | IF simpleExpression THEN stmtMatched elsifList . ELSE selectionStmtUnmatched

   ELSIF  shift, and go to state 167
   ELSE   shift, and go to state 168

   ELSIF     [reduce using rule 48 (selectionStmtUnmatched)]
   ELSE      [reduce using rule 48 (selectionStmtUnmatched)]
   $default  reduce using rule 48 (selectionStmtUnmatched)
```

Answer (score 0):

The grammar in your handout does not allow an unmatched statement before an `else`. Why is that?

It's because the `else` must bind to the closest not-yet-matched `if`. You might want to try doing a few parse trees by hand to understand how this works. The essential point is that inside the unmatched statement, there is an unmatched `if` which the `else` should bind to. So the ambiguity can be removed by removing the possibility of skipping over that unmatched `if`.

Now, what changes when we add `elsif`? Not much. Both `elsif` and `else` must bind to the closest not-yet-matched `if` or `elsif`. And the way of guaranteeing that is exactly the same as the simple case. We need to ensure that the statement *before* the `elsif` is matched.

But your grammar only requires that the statement before the *first* `elsif` be matched. So ambiguities remain.

As a hint: the fix is very simple. You just need to do the grouping differently.

Comment: I posted an update with the advice on ensuring that elsif are only preceded by matched statements and would love to hear some feedback.

Comment: Also you say that the grammar only requires that statement before the first elsif be matched and that still leaves us with ambiguities. Could you explain that a little more?

Comment: @corbin: I know you are new here. For future reference, please do not change questions after they have been answered. This is not a dialogue; it tries to be a repository of questions of general application and applicable answers. Changing the question invalidates the answer, or at least makes it confusing for future readers.

Comment: When I said the grammar only requires the statement before the first `elsif` to be matched, I was referring to the grammar in your original question. In that grammar it is evident that the statement following an `elsif` is not restricted, so if there is a second `elsif` in the list, the statement before the second `elsif` is not required to be matched by the grammar. That means the grammar is ambiguous because it allows the `elsif` to skip over un unmatched `if`/`elsif` and bind to a different `if`/`elsif` than the closest unmatched one.

Comment: That may be a bit hard to follow, but it should be easy to see if you draw out a few parse trees on paper.

Comment: @CorbinSchueller: just for clarification: I'm pretty sure that the S/R conflicts in your last grammar are just S/R conflicts, not ambiguities. Also, I don't think your last grammar will correctly parse, for example, `if ( e ) then s2 elsif (e2) then if (e3) then s3`, because the grammar seems to insist that the statement following `elsif` be matched. I haven't tried any of that because I don't t have ready access to a computer today.